# Oracle Apex span static content region across entire page

Tags: css, oracle-apex

Simple question, I'm wondering if it's possible to span a static content region across the entire page? That way there's no whitespace around all sides of my region. Only thing I could think to try was `style = "width:100%"` which still leaves some padding between the region and the vertical navigation menu and the scroll bar. Red line defines the whitespace I'm attempting to get rid of.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at creating a custom page template just for this ? Maybe there already is a page template available that suits this requirement.

Comment: I have never created a custom template before, will do some research/learning and get back to you. Thanks for the advice!